# Autocomplete file names in current working directory Notepad++ Project

Tags: notepad++, tab-completion

This maybe a stupid question, but I can't seem to find an answer. Is there a way or a plugin that allows you to autocomplete file names that exist in the current working directory of an open project in Notepad++?

I have an R project, and the tab complete for file names is useful in R studio, and I was hoping there was a way for Notepad++ to do the same. I have search online, and found instructions on the Auto completion settings under preferences, but that seems to only draw from a pre-defined .xml file.

Am I stuck copying and pasting the file names from the directory tree? 
Thanks!